# & and * operators making my fread() succeed in C

Tags: c, file, linked-list, fread

Okay, so when I use this block of code

```
fread(&(*list) -> books, sizeof(struct NOVEL), 1, fpread);
```

Everything works fine.

However, when I use this

```
fread (list -> books, sizeof(struct NOVEL), 1, fpread);
```

I get this error: Member reference base type 'LISTNODEPTR' (aka 'struct listnode *') is not a structure or union.

I thought that * and & cancel each other out, so why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
*list
```

is a struct pointer,

```
list
```

is a pointer to a struct pointer.

So to access the books field you need: (*list) -> books

You need to get your precedence straight: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

```
&(*list) -> books
```

is the same as

```
&((*list) -> books)
```

It is not the same as

```
list -> books
```